# distinct integers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> Given a zero-based permutation nums (0-indexed), build an array ans of the
> same length where ans[i] = nums[nums[i]] for each 0 <= i < nums.length and
> return it.
> A zero-based permutation nums is an array of distinct integers from 0 to
> nums.length - 1 (inclusive).

Example 1:

```
Input: nums = [0,2,1,5,3,4]
Output: [0,1,2,4,5,3]
```

```
    nums = [0,2,1,5,3,4]
var buildArray = function(nums) {
    return nums.map(n => nums[n]);
};
console.log(buildArray(nums))
```

Can any one explain dry run of this and why it is giving output as shown above and what is distinct integers?

Comment: Array of distinct integer means all numbers in the array are unique that is all numbers occur only once.

Comment: need more explanation and how it is showing out as [0,1,2,4,5,3] when we are mapping @PR7

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will help you understand what is going on in the code. All examples will produce same result. In the example using `map`, `n` is equivalent to `nums[i]`.

```js
const nums = [0, 2, 1, 5, 3, 4];

// Using Array.map()
var buildArray = function(nums) {
  return nums.map(n => nums[n]);
};
console.log('Using Array.map() : ', buildArray(nums))

// Using Array.map() with index
var buildArray2 = function(nums) {
  return nums.map((n, i) => nums[nums[i]]);
};
console.log('Using Array.map() with index : ', buildArray2(nums))

// Using For Loop
let ans = new Array(nums.length);
for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  ans[i] = nums[nums[i]];
}
console.log('Using for loop : ', ans);
```

Comment: Thank you @PR7, now I got the flow of code

Answer (score -2):

```
var buildArray = function(nums) {

    const arr =new Array(nums.length);
       for(let i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
       arr[i]=nums[nums[i]]
    }
    nums.forEach((i)=>{
      arr[i]=nums[nums[i]]
    })
    return arr
}
```

both solution are correct use according to your choice